# Time Complexity: Does the following problem belong to NP?

Tags: time-complexity

> Suppose n people live in a house and wish to share their expenses
> equally. Their respective expenses (before settling) are x1, ..., xn.
> They agree to write checks to each other so as to make all their net
> expenses equal. Naturally, they want to use as few checks as possible.
>
> SETTLEMENT denotes the decision version of this problem: Given
> nonnegative integers x1, . . . , xn (written in binary) and an integer
> k, can the net expenses be balanced using k or fewer checks?

I am not sure if I am understanding this problem correctly.. So, given the information, k is a balanced net expense, right? We should find the average net expense of {x1,...,xn}, where x1,...,xn represent the respective expenses. So, SETTLEMENT is as follows:

SETTLEMENT = {(x1,…,xn; k) : there exists some k such that (x1+x2+...+xn) / n = k}.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to credit the original source of all copied material.  https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is incorrect. The value of $k$ is not an expense, $k$ is the minimum number of checks needed to make sure that the **net** amount of money paid by each person is $\overline{x} = \frac{1}{n} =\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

For example if $n=2$, $x_1=1$, $x_2=5$ then $\overline{x}=3$ and $k=1$. In particular it suffices from the 1st person to write a check to the 2nd person for an amount of $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That quite makes sense.

Comment: I constructed the algorithm to compute this: For each expense xi, if it is less or more than X, then that person writes a check to the next person for an amount of the difference. By this algorithm that is in polynomial time, we intuitively know there will be k or fewer checks necessary to make the net expenses balanced. What do you think about this?

Comment: I think that your algorithm doesn't work. Counterexample: $x_1 = 3$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=1$. Your algorithm uses $2$ checks but only one check is needed.

Comment: What about this: For each expense xi, if it is less or more than X, then that person writes a check for an amount of the difference to the next person whose expense is not equal to X.

Comment: That algorithm could prescribe to write checks of negative amounts. Besides, even when this doesn't happen, the algorithm doesn't work. Counterexample: $x_1 = 4$, $x_2 =1$, $x_3=3$, $x_4=0$. Your algorithm writes at least $3$ checks yet the optimal solution uses $2$ checks. In general, I don't think that it is useful for you to guess an algorithm and use me as an oracle to provide you with counterexamples. Try to prove yourself that your algorithm doesn't work. If you consistently fail to do so, then try to write down a *formal* proof of correctness. Repeat until a solution is found :)

Comment: Can you explain how the optimal solution uses 2 checks?

Comment: Send a check of value $2$ from $x_1$ to $x_4$. Send a check of value $1$ from $x_3$ to $x_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!